# Python script throws module not found error in pm2 but works in cmd

Tags: python, pm2

I want to demonise a python script with pm2 that worked before.
I've created a venv with Python 3.6.8. I installed all modules that are required and tryed the script via console, which works.
But if I start the module via pm2, I get an ModuleNotFound Error:

[image]

For all the other 23 scripts it worked as well with pm2.
The venv Python version is 3.6.8, the same as the version from the other venv where it was running before.

Has someone encountered similar behaviour and can give me some suggestions on what I could try to solve the issue?
Reinstalling the module doesn't help.

Comment: Did you specify the `interpreter` to the `python executable` in your virtualenv?

Comment: I just tried that:
npx pm2 start 18 --interpreter python3
after your surgesstion, but it failed again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specified the absolute path of your virtual environment

`pm2 start 18 --interpreter /path/to/your/.venv/bin/python3`

Also remember to check whether is the package exists:

```py
/path/to/your/.venv/bin/python3 -m pip list
```

Comment: Okay, that worked. But I still don't really understand why ;(
But thank you very much anyway, you made my day ;)

Comment: Your default `python` can not locate the package since you install it to your venv, which is independent from the global module search path.